# Bash error [: : integer expression expected"

Tags: bash, shell

I'm getting into the error for bash shell `[: : integer expression expected"` while running below script.

```
#!/bin/bash
sm=$(ps -e | grep sendmail > /dev/null 2>&1)
pm=$(/etc/init.d/postfix status > /dev/null 2>&1)
check_mail(){
if [ "$sm" -eq 0 ]; then
echo "Service Status: Sendmail is Running!"
elif [ "$pm" -eq 0 ]; then
echo "Service Status: Postfix Service is Running!"
else
echo "Service Status: Both Sendmail & Postfix Service is Not Running On $(uname -n)"
fi
}
check_mail
```

> While running the above script it's simply showing the output of `else`
>   condition.

`Service Status: Both Sendmail & Postfix Service is Not Running On host`

Though, i have tested "==" rather "-eq"  for comparison and  `[[]]` but did not worked.

Comment: You send all the output to devnull, so there will be nothing in your vars.

Comment: @123, even with not redirecting output to `/dev/null 2>&1` giving the `integer ` error.

Comment: Because neither of those commands outputs an integer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you are trying to assess presence of sendmail in the process list.  You should change your code to this :

```
#!/bin/bash
check_mail(){
if
  ps -e | grep sendmail > /dev/null 2>&1
then
  echo "Service Status: Sendmail is Running!"
elif
  /etc/init.d/postfix status > /dev/null 2>&1
then
  echo "Service Status: Postfix Service is Running!"
else
  echo "Service Status: Both Sendmail & Postfix Service is Not Running On $(uname -n)"
fi
}
check_mail
```

The reason your original code fails is that you capture the output of commands using command substitution `$()`.  The standard output, that is, not the exit code.  Then, when using the `[ -eq ]` test, which expects an integer argument (which your variable does not contain), it fails with the message you get.  Since both tests always fail, the `else` clause is entered.

By putting the actual commands inside the conditions of the `if` statement, you are using the actual numerical return code (`0` for true, non-zero for false), which is what you want here.

Comment: I tried the same code as well before but same error.

Comment: You cannot see the `[: : integer expression expected` error in the code I proposed, because there is no `[` test in that code.

Comment: @Fred.....My bad.. You are correct , but in your code we are directly evaluating the condition from `ps -e | grep service` and not testing it via test conditions.. I tried the same with the test `[]` condition and that fails, Just updated the another code what i tried..

Comment: @Karn I am not sure I understand what you mean.  Direct evaluation from the command is what you need, and getting rid of `[ ]` is what you should do.  It is the solution, not the problem.  The `if` statement does not need a test in the form of `[ ]` or `[[ ]]`, the return code of any command will do the job too.

Comment: Both the answers are correct though, i'm accepting @Fred's answer since he posted first, However i voted both as well.

Answer (score 2):

It seems to me that you are confusing the exit-status of a program with the output.`var=$(command)` will put the output of `command` in `var`. As said in 123's comment, because you redirect everything to `/dev/null`, there is no output, and therefore, `sm` and `pm` are empty.

If you want to see the exit status, use `$?`:

```
#!/bin/bash
typeset -i pm
typeset -i sm
ps -e | grep sendmail > /dev/null 2>&1
sm=$?
/etc/init.d/postfix status > /dev/null 2>&1
pm=$?

check_mail(){
    if [ $sm -eq 0 ]; then
        echo "Service Status: Sendmail is Running!"
    elif [ $pm -eq 0 ]; then
        echo "Service Status: Postfix Service is Running!"
    else
        echo "Service Status: Both Sendmail & Postfix Service is Not Running On $(uname -n)"
    fi
}
check_mail
```

Comment: @Ljm....I just update my post where i applied the test condition and even its not yielding the correct Status and producing the `integer` error as well.

Comment: Ah yes, remove the quotes. I missed that one. Full script in now in the answer.

Comment: in Bash typeset is deprecated.